# Metricbeat retrieving total CPU overall utilization (and not 'usage' or 'load')

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

CPU utilization is not the same as CPU load is not the same as CPU usage.

taken definitions of CPU usage and load from [here](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/linux-cpu-load/) and the corresponding metricbeat fields from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/exported-fields-system.html):

- CPU usage:

  > CPU usage is a measurement, in a percentage, of how much time the CPU spends actively
  > computing something.

  available on `system.cpu.system.pct`

  [image]
  this picture shows how much time my host's CPU cores were busy computing something.
- CPU load:

  > CPU load measures how many programs are using or waiting for a processor core at one
  > time.

  load metric is not available on windows hosts.
- CPU utilization

  > CPU utilization refers to a computer's usage of processing resources.
  > mean overall resource usage of any core.

  for example, currently, my windows host utilizes 24% of his CPU resource.

  [image]

I would like to monitor my host CPU utilization and not CPU usage using metricbeat. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Metricbeat measures CPU use as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-system.html#_cpu_2;

> CPU statistics (idle, irq, user, system, iowait, softirq, cores, nice, steal, total)....

utilisation would be a dynamic and relative calculation, it's not something Metricbeat is setup to do. you could always file a feature request to have it considered though - https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/new/choose

Comment: how can I calculate it from the already given stats?

Comment: find out what 100% usage is for your system and then go from there. I am not sure what the best way to do that is though sorry, because 100% is relative